# is it possible to reference .linq file in LinqPad

Tags: linqpad

is it possible to call/reference functions in another query file beside MyExtensions in LinqPad?

Comment: Both of the answers were, effectively, written by [Joe Albahari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46223/joe-albahari), the author of LINQPad, but six years apart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As of May 2019](https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1869/including-one-linq-file-inside-another-please-comment) it is possible now https://www.linqpad.net/LinqReference.aspx

> In LINQPad 6 and later, queries can reference other queries with the #load directive:
>
> #load "SomeOtherQuery.linq"   // The #load directive must appear be at the top of the query

Util.linq:

```cs
void Main() { }
                
void OpenWithAssociatedApp (string file)
{
    Process.Start (new ProcessStartInfo (file) { UseShellExecute = true });
}

class ConnectionStrings
{
    public static string Test = "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true;Database=test";
}
```

Some other query:

```cs
#load "Util.linq"

void Main()
{
    File.WriteAllText ("foo.txt", "test");

    OpenWithAssociatedApp ("foo.txt");  // Calls OpenWithAssociatedApp in Util.linq
    ConnectionStrings.Test.Dump();      // Reads ConnectionStrings.Test in Util.linq
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call one script from another:

> Another way to combine scripts is to dynamically execute one script from another. The `Util.Run` method does exactly that, and is useful in both interactive and command-line scenarios:
>
> ```
> string htmlResult = Util.Run ("test.linq", QueryResultFormat.Html).AsString();
> ```
>
> Note: If you feed `Util.Run` a relative path, it will resolve it relative to the 'My Queries' directory rather than the current directory. You can switch its behavior by specifying `.\test.linq` instead of `test.linq` in this example.

From:

- [LINQPad Command-Line and Scripting](https://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No, this [isn't possible right now](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/199744-make-it-possible-to-reference-and-execute-linq-fi).